# Regex to replace all numbers after first 3 numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am using the java regex engine and need a way to remove all numbers after the first 3 digits in the string. I have tried a positive look behind but that didnt work.

Here is the type of data i have

```
213-333-4444

233.444.5556

(636) 434-5555
```

This the result i am trying to reach:

```
213-222-2222

233.222.2222

(636) 222-2222
```

So the regex would look for the first 3 digits and past that replace all numeric charecters with 2s.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Please show us some code.

Comment: How did you try to implement the positive look behind?

Comment: Here is what i have tried i know it isnt correct that is why i am asking it here: ^(?<=[0-9]{3})$

Comment: Do you always have first 3 characters adjacent?

Comment: @dims yes they will always be adjacent but wont always be right at the start of the string

Comment: Do you always have `\\d{3}[.-]\\d{4}` kind of pattern at the end?

Comment: @RohitJain numbers could be separated by dashes, spaces, periods, parentheses or no separation at all. If i get the basic regex right i can make it fancy to include all these specifics main part i am looking for is a way to confirm that 3 digits already exist in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
    String[] strings = {
            "213-333-4444",
            "233.444.5556",
            "(636) 434-5555"
    };
    String regex = "(\\D*\\d{3}\\D*)[\\d]{3}(.?)[\\d]{4}";
    String replacement = "$1222$22222";
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex, replacement));
    }
```

output:

```
213-222-2222
233.222.2222
(636) 222-2222
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't force to do it with single regexp, use several. For example, determine the final location of last number of three, and then run simple number replacing regexp from that position.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution in this way..Try with it..

```
int count=0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d|\\D)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("213-333-4444");  //change this according to your need
while (m.find()) {
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
    Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(m.group());
    if(m1.find())
    {
        count++;
        if(count>3)
            System.out.print(m.group().replace(m.group(), "2"));
        else
             System.out.print(m.group());
    }
    else
        System.out.print(m.group());
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using a regex, why not loop through each character of the string starting from the 4th element (Since you want the first 3 to remain) and check if its a number or not and carry out desired operation.

Comment: I am using a tool which forces me to use Java regex engine...